# SSH.NET with Azure Functions on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, nuget, azure-functions, ssh.net

I am trying to run a simple SFTP client with Azure functions, using Visual Studio 2015.
The problem is that I do not know how to add the nuget reference to SSH.NET.
In `project.json` have tried to add:

```
{
"net40": {
  "dependencies": {
    "Renci.SshNet": "2016.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

}
}

I have tried using `"net46:"` too, but I keep getting `NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/renci.sshnet/index.json` regardless of what I do.

I might need to add a few more nuget packages later so I'd like to know how to generally add nuget packages to my functions project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "SSH.NET": "2016.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: Also note that the new tooling in Visual Studio 2017 uses the standard .NET csproj for these dependencies along with standard nuget and other VS tools, so it might be worth checking that out.

Comment: That actually worked! I no longer get any complaints about the nuget package.
But none of my code can use it?! "using Renci.SshNet" and all my related code is not recognized